# Replacing dots with underscores, when using make.names or renaming obejcts in the working environment

Tags: r, lapply

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once) (ill advised, I know) solution to automatically name Excel files when uploading a folder.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
list2env(
  lapply(setNames(temp, make.names(gsub("*.csv$", "", temp))), 
         read.csv), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Now, `make.names` uses `.` to make correct names, while I would rather use `_`. What would be the best way to dynamically change the dots to underscores?

I tried to do something like  `lapply(ls(),gsub(".", "_"))`, but that does not seem to work.
I would also prefer to do it within `list2env`, but I'll settle for a separate line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably that use you use `"."` which in a regex matches every character. If you want to match a `.` in a string you have to escape it using  use `"\\."`.

Personally I don't like it to wrangle all code in one line when you could use a simple function to make the code cleaner and more understandable.

```r
# Example data
write.csv(mtcars, "mt cars.csv")
write.csv(mtcars, "mt car s.csv")

temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")

make_names <- function(x) {
  gsub("\\.", "_", make.names(gsub("*.csv$", "", x)))
}
names(temp) <- make_names(temp)

list2env(lapply(temp, read.csv), envir = .GlobalEnv)
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

ls()
#> [1] "make_names" "mt_car_s"   "mt_cars"    "temp"
```